# Dry + (out / off / up)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions, verbs, phrasal-verbs

I was wondering which choice is correct in each example below:

**First case:**

> I spilled a glass of water on the table last night, but Candy came by and we left the home immediately  so I didn't clean the table. Today, when I came back I saw that it had ..... on its own. 
> a. [dried](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dry) 
> b. [dried out](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dry-out) 
> c. [dried off](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dry-sb-sth-off?q=dry%20off) 
> d. [dried up](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dry-up)

**Second case:**

> Put the cap back on the marker or its tip will... 
> a. [dry](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dry). 
> b. dry out. 
> c. [dry off](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dry-sb-sth-off?q=dry%20off). 
> d. [dry up](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dry-up).

As you can see, the dictionary definitions do not let a learner to choose between the prepositions. I would appreciate it if you kindly could give me a hand with them.

Comment: I think 'candy' is a noun (someone's name), so it should be __Candy__. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: That was a typo @Dhanishtha Ghosh. Thank you for pointing that out. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These phrases are very similar. Often, more than one will be appropriate. I will try to explain the differences.

A. Dry - The most simple. Something wet becomes more or completely dry.

B. Dry out - Something that you is wet throughout(e.g. the tip of a marker pen or clothes that have soaked up water) has become completely or almost completely dry.

C. Dry off - Something has water on the outside of it(often droplets) and the water is being removed, usually to put it in a more appropriate state for what it will be needed for next. Often but not always due to some external action, such as using a wiping with a towel. Commonly used for someone getting out of a pool.

D. Dry up - A pool or resevoir of liquid dries to the point of having no liquid left. E.g. a spill or a river

Based on these we can choose the appropriate option(s) for your sentences.

Sentence 1:
The spill has become more dry so A is fine.
The spill is on the table not soaked in so B is inappropriate.
Using C implies that the table has done some action to dry itself so this not appropriate.
The spill was a pool of liquid and it has completely dried so D is fine.

> I saw that it had dried/dried up

Sentence 2:

A. The tip is wet and will become more dry so A is appropriate.

B. The tip is wet throughout and will become more dry so B is appropriate.

C. The tip does not have liquid on the outside of it and is not doing any action to dry itself so C is inappropriate.

D. The tip has a resevoir of liquid that will run out of water so D is appropriate.

> Put the cap back on the marker or its tip will dry/dry out/ dry up

Comment: Thank you very much @ededededed87. May I invite you to the chat forum so that I could raise more questions? It would be really helpful to me.

Comment: Yeah. No problem

Comment: Thank you very much dedededed87. Here is the link: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115385/dry-out-off-up